# script to load balance webpages

Tags: load-balancing, scripting

Im new with shell scripting, and I need help, to create this scripts.

I have 2 apache (active/standby) servers, and what I need is to have one script that will check the status of the server 1 (wget or services) and if the services of the web is down,i will need to have this script to connect to the second server and start the apache services.

Thanks all.!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like `keepalived` which check the health of your servers. I really like the article from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-web-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04). Maybe this answer all your questions.

Comment: thanks for the share but i was looking for something simple, thanks!!!!

Comment: @tcpip keepalived is hardly complex for something as simple as you want. If this is too much, write your own script to get the http or systemctl status (or sth.), react to it by SSHing to the second machine and start up apache. But Markus is right, no need to reinvent the wheel if not completely necessary.